# in a multilanguage application using MVC, would the files that contain the language variables be part of the model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am at the point of finally understanding the MVC programming concept. So the question is if you are creating a web application in php that is multilingual(ie, English and Spanihs), do the language files containing the translated texts(ie, $go_to start = 'Go to Start') fall into the Model part of the MVC concept?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no:

- **Yes:** if you're storing localised values into the database, then the models will handle this.
- **No:** localisations/translations generally would fall into the "view" area. Whether they are separate templates, or whether various locale specific translation files are loaded and then rendered to the browser, they're part of the view.

As a general rule it should be the controllers and the views that are locale/language aware. Models should be agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

In almost every framework there is a kind of 'dictionary' that SHOULD HAVE all of the 'visible strings'.

Then, by a setting, the current language is selected.

To translate to another language you only should make a copy of this 'dictionary' and replace this strings to another language.

I've made this with Django (is Python) but in almost in every framework is similar